# Migration from Flex 3 to Flex 4 Errors

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4, migration, compiler-errors

Hello I migrated my Flex 3 project to FLex 4: I am getting these errors:

Anyone has an idea about fixing this in Flex 4.

```
1061: Call to a possibly undefined method activate through a reference with static type mx.managers:ISystemManager.
1061: Call to a possibly undefined method activate through a reference with static type mx.managers:ISystemManager.
1061: Call to a possibly undefined method activate through a reference with static type mx.managers:ISystemManager.
1061: Call to a possibly undefined method activate through a reference with static type mx.managers:ISystemManager.
1061: Call to a possibly undefined method addFocusManager through a reference with static type mx.managers:ISystemManager.
1061: Call to a possibly undefined method addFocusManager through a reference with static type mx.managers:ISystemManager.
1061: Call to a possibly undefined method addFocusManager through a reference with static type mx.managers:ISystemManager.
1061: Call to a possibly undefined method addFocusManager through a reference with static type mx.managers:ISystemManager.
1061: Call to a possibly undefined method removeFocusManager through a reference with static type mx.managers:ISystemManager.
1061: Call to a possibly undefined method removeFocusManager through a reference with static type mx.managers:ISystemManager.
1061: Call to a possibly undefined method removeFocusManager through a reference with static type mx.managers:ISystemManager.
1061: Call to a possibly undefined method removeFocusManager through a reference with static type mx.managers:ISystemManager.
1144: Interface method addPopUp in namespace mx.managers:IPopUpManager is implemented with an incompatible signature in class mx.managers:PopUpManagerImpl. 
1144: Interface method addPopUp in namespace mx.managers:IPopUpManager is implemented with an incompatible signature in class mx.managers:PopUpManagerImpl. 
1144: Interface method addPopUp in namespace mx.managers:IPopUpManager is implemented with an incompatible signature in class mx.managers:PopUpManagerImpl. 
1144: Interface method addPopUp in namespace mx.managers:IPopUpManager is implemented with an incompatible signature in class mx.managers:PopUpManagerImpl. 
1144: Interface method createPopUp in namespace mx.managers:IPopUpManager is implemented with an incompatible signature in class mx.managers:PopUpManagerImpl.  
1144: Interface method createPopUp in namespace mx.managers:IPopUpManager is implemented with an incompatible signature in class mx.managers:PopUpManagerImpl.  
1144: Interface method createPopUp in namespace mx.managers:IPopUpManager is implemented with an incompatible signature in class mx.managers:PopUpManagerImpl.  
1144: Interface method createPopUp in namespace mx.managers:IPopUpManager is implemented with an incompatible signature in class mx.managers:PopUpManagerImpl.
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You'd better list lines which highlighted with compiler errors.

Comment: @Constantiner Usually errors like this have no line numbers and relate to a version mismatch between a library and the main project.  ( See my answer ).  If you downvoted b/c of the lack of detail, I suggest you remove your downvote because I honestly believe the original poster had no more additional detail to provide.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com No, I did't downvoted and I supposed these errors hadn't particular lines but I thought it will be better if topic starter pointed that fact :)

Comment: @Constantiner I hate when people downvote w/o saying why. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Errors like this are usually due to version mismatch issues.  So, make sure that all your external libraries are compiled with the same version of the Flex SDK that your main project is.

If you are using frameworks, or other libraries you found on the web you may have to recompile them yourself if the source code is available.

Comment: Hello,

In fact in the flex 3 project there is a class called PopUpManagerImpl.as. It is from this file that am getting all these errors.

If possible to put some light on this.
Thanks

Comment: @FlexyBoz I'm not sure what else to tel you other than what I already said.  This problem usually doesn't relate to a specific class throwing errors; it usually relates to a library being compiled in a different version of the Flex SDK than the main project.  There isn't [as far as I know] code you can change to make this go away.  You need to recompile your libraries to use the same version of the Flex SDK.